# Как обозначить открытие файла для чтения/записи в блок-схеме?

Tags: c, блок-схема

Мне нужно сделать блок-схему для программы на языке C. Раз открытие файла - это действие, значит по идее мне стоит отобразить его на схеме..? Однако я не понимаю, какой именно блок мне нужно выбрать. По-моему это должен быть либо длинный шестиугольник, либо длинный прямоугольник. Подскажите пожалуйста что из этого мне подойдёт.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Вспоминая блок схемы, можно заметить что это БЛОК схема! Что такое блок? Это несколько действий в одном. Чтение файла это ввод данных, обозначается прямоугольником с косыми двумя сторонами :)
Я так стар, что помню это ;) В общем это блок ввода-вывода.

Comment: @FrancNet, ага, ромбоид (параллелограмм) тоже вспомнил сразу. Глянул Википедию, смотрю ещё есть блок "документ" .

Comment: Есть ещё прямоугольник с двойными боковушками - "сложный процесс, не описанный на данной схеме"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Файл как документ обозначается как прямоугольник с волной. Подходит если файл является объектом процесса.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ромбоид подходит больше чем шестиугольник и прямоугольник.

Comment: Ну если принять это решение, то это будет новый блок в блок-схемах :)
Ромбоид (как его назвал eri) будет уместнее, так как по сути, чтение из файла это ввод данных!
Нужно придерживаться существующим стандартам, для совместимости и понимания другими вашей блок-схемы, если вы не создаете новые стандарты ;)
Тогда хоть ромашку рисуйте :)

Comment: Почему новый? Вполне стандартный. В чертилках диаграмм есть.

Comment: На английской вики блок называется так, ромбоид) https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B4